# Knockout.js dynamicly generated HTML not getting updates

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, knockout.js

I have a rather complex system working in the background, will try to give the briefest and shortest example:

I have a single PHP/HTML page which fires an Ajax call to the server and gets a response XML back. Based on the XML the javascript dynamically creates a bunch of DOM elements. The XML also contains data which I map to a view model of the knockout that is present on the main page.

However elements are not getting updated, or rather the knockout.js is not interacting with them at all (and I will assume that ko.applyBinding(model) is to blame.

Here is what I need:
 1. load a single PHP page that holds the knockout.js and a view model object.
 2. send an AJAX request which returns the new Data to update the model with as well as new HTML DOM elements that get added into the page.
 3. have knockout.js keep track of the data information in these new elements.

The problem from what I see is that ko.applyBinding(model) gets fired BEFORE the HTML elements are present within the DOM, thus they never get bound, however there is simply NO WAY to know which elements will be added and what data will be pulled from the server and it has to remain dynamic.

I've figgured that if I could re-apply the binding it would work (I think) but trying to do so gives an error. I've read in couple of other posts that there is no way to reapply the binding for the entire document but that it has to be done separately for each element however these elements would then have to be siblings in the DOM, which doesn't work for me as they need to be nested.

**Any ideas on the solution?**

**EDIT:** Made a JSFiddle example, however since I cannot include knockout-mapping.js into it, it doesn't work so I've prepared the .HTML document and added the needed libraries (knockout.js and knockout-mapping.js), linked them all together and uploaded them up [here](https://yadi.sk/d/S4ltovt7q6Mih) It is a .rar file with everything setup and the libraries included.

**EDIT2:**
A short preview of what is needed can also be seen below:

```js
var ViewModel = {
  buttonOneText: ko.observable("Button 1")
}

ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);

// IMAGINARY AJAX HAPPENS
// when this happens I need to add another button into the frameDiv and add it's data to the model.

document.getElementById("frameDiv").innerHTML += '<button type="button" data-bind="text: buttonTwoText"></button>'
ViewModel.buttonTwoText = "Button 2";

ko.applyBindings(ViewModel, document.getElementById("frameDiv"));

//    So far this works, and it is great!
//    If you comment out the rest of the JS code it will work perfectly
//    problem comes when you attempt to add a thrid element, because
//    even though "frameDiv" has no bind-data, it doesn't let you run it
//    again on that div.

document.getElementById("frameDiv").innerHTML += '<button type="button" data-bind="text: buttonThreeText"></button>'
ViewModel.buttonThreeText = "Button 3";

ko.applyBindings(ViewModel, document.getElementById("frameDiv"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div id="frameDiv">
  <button type="button" data-bind="text: buttonOneText"></button>

  <!-- The following element will be added VIA Javascript code -->
  <!--<button type="button" data-bind="text: buttonTwoText"></button>-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide a second argument to `ko.applyBindings` that specifies the top node to apply the bindings to. You can call this on any nodes that you create, as long as you haven't put already-bound nodes under them.

Here's a little example script with a routine that creates a new DOM node, inserts it, and applies bindings to it. Click the button to execute the routine.

```js
parser = new DOMParser();
foo = 1;

vm = {
  makeNode: function() {
    var el = parser.parseFromString('<div data-bind="text:' + foo + '"></div>', "text/xml").childNodes[0];
    ++foo;
    document.getElementById('foo').appendChild(el);
    ko.applyBindings(vm, el);
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">
</div>
<button data-bind="click: makeNode">Add node</button>
```

Comment: Let me just get this straight: Let's say I have an HTML dom tree that has been passed in it's entirety to the initial ko.applyBindings(model)  without the second argument (defaulting to body). Do all the elements get their bindings set or only the ones that actually have data-bind attribute? And to  continue from there, if I was to override one of these elements with a new element from my AJAX call, could I then bind that new element (and it's children) even if the previous one was already bound?

Comment: Fair question. If an element didn't have any `data-bind` on it, it would not have any bindings, and I don't think Knockout will consider it already bound if you try to bind again.
If you remove a bound element and replace it (as I take your "override"), the replacement would need to be bound. If you just change the `data-bind` attribute and bind again, problem.
Mostly, this should not be an issue. You should be using templates or components to avoid these situations if possible.

Comment: Templates are out of the question but I think that if what you say is true then this solves the issue. I have a page layout that has a "container" div in which the content will be put, the container itself has no data-binding but before the ajax call is made the entire <body> is ran through the applyBinding() method, including this container. At a later point I would do an AJAX, fill the container with content, update the view model with ko.mapping(data, {}, viewmodel.data) and use ko.applyBinding to just that container again just binding it's childeren and not itself, since no data-bind.

Comment: Will check when I am back at work on monday, hope it works, but I am very much afraid it won't

Comment: Sadly, even if the element has no data-bind attribute you cannot apply the binding to it multiple times, so it doesn't solve the issue.  If you have any other ideas I would love to hear them, I'll edit the main post to more accurately reflect what I need.

Comment: @Dellierium Insert a new div before the existing one, delete the old one, and insert into and bind the new one.

Comment: But if I was to delete the existing one that would delete all of it's content and more importantly it's event handlers. Contentwise i could clone the required Div, but that wouldn't affect the handlers in the code. If nothing else ends up working i will have to check with our architecture designer to redesign how this is implemented because it seems that it won't happen this way.

Comment: @Dellirium I guess I misunderstood. I thought you had an unbound, empty div. If it contains bound elements, you can't applyBindings on it again, because applyBindings is recursive. You can call `applyBindings` on each of the new elements individually.

Comment: As it is now, the element is empty, and for all the current needs it will be empty, however I don't know if two months down the road someone will decide to change that, so I am taking it into the account when making this.

The example I made shows that even if there is a bound element present within the element the binding will work, but only the first time.

If you have an non-bound div with a bound child and reapply the binding to the container div, it works. If you then do it one more time, it fails. IDK why. But I will mark this resolved for now. Thanks for aid!